# Parsing XML file returns the wrong type. Needs to return Location element

Tags: c#

I am parsing XML text returned from here:

https://ims.gov.il/sites/default/files/ims_data/xml_files/isr_cities_1week_6hr_forecast.xml.

This is a very lengthy file, but I will show a minimal sampling of its contents below.

I want to find a city based on its `LocationId` and I tried to obtain the `Location` element using this expression, but `city` is not an XElement.

```
IEnumerable city = xmlFile.Descendants("Forecast").Where(item => (int)item.Parent.Element("LocationId") == 4);
```

My first question is how to correctly retrieve the `city` based on its `LocationId` in order to list the forecasts for that location. Also, from that list of forecasts, how can I obtain a single data element like `Temperature`?

**This is a subset of the XML Data**

```
<LocationForecasts>
    <Identification>
        <Organization>Israel Meteorological Service</Organization>
        <Title>6-hours forecast for 80 cities</Title>
        <IssueDateTime>Sun Jul 17 18:45:24 IDT 2022</IssueDateTime>
    </Identification>
    <Location>
        <LocationMetaData>
            <LocationId>1</LocationId>
            <LocationNameEng>Jerusalem</LocationNameEng>
            <DisplayLat>31.7780</DisplayLat>
            <DisplayLon>35.2000</DisplayLon>
            <DisplayHeight>780</DisplayHeight>
        </LocationMetaData>
        <LocationData>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 03:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>19</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>90</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>6</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>113</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>17</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>18</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>0</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>19</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>19</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>19</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>20</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>0</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>0</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
         </LocationData>
    </Location>    <Location>
        <LocationMetaData>
            <LocationId>4</LocationId>
            <LocationNameEng>Rishon le Zion</LocationNameEng>
            <DisplayLat>31.9640</DisplayLat>
            <DisplayLon>34.8040</DisplayLon>
            <DisplayHeight>50</DisplayHeight>
        </LocationMetaData>
        <LocationData>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 03:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>24</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>76</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>3</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>360</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>19</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>22</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>0</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>24</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>24</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>21</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>26</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>0</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>0</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 09:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>28</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>64</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>9</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>68</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>20</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>25</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>2</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>29</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>28</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>22</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>28</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>4</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>4</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 15:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>29</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>56</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>18</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>113</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>20</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>26</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>2</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>31</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>29</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>28</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>30</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>6</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>10</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 21:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>26</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>68</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>8</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>180</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>20</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>24</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>1</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>26</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>26</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1250</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>26</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>30</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>0</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>4</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
        </LocationData>
    </Location> 
</LocationForecasts>";
```

Comment: bro, share your code... and please paste the XML as text

Comment: Youe post contains _no question at all_. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of good tutorials for `System.Xml.Linq`. When you use an expression like `xmlFile.Descendants("Forecast")` it returns a collection, so you might want to look at expressions like `First` and `Single` that can be applied to collections.

Under the hood, each of these is an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for `XContainer`. And once you get more familiar with the basics, you may want to consider writing *your own* extensions that are tailored to your specific use case. This is what I suggest to answer your question about parsing.

---

Here I made a "Top-level static class" named `Extensions` and it contains two custom methods to assist you with the outcome you want. It is the keyword `this` in the first argument that identifies these as extension methods.

```
static class Extensions
{
    // Return true if Id matches
    public static bool IsMatchLocationId(this XElement xLocation, int id)
    {
        if (xLocation.Name.LocalName != "Location") return false;
        var meta = xLocation.Element("LocationMetaData");
        if (meta == null) return false;
        var locationId = meta.Element("LocationId");
        if (locationId == null) return false;
        return id == (int)locationId;
    }
    // Return a formatted string for a Forecast element
    public static string Format(this XElement xForecast)
    {
        // THIS IS JUST A BASIC EXAMPLE
        return $"\tTime: {xForecast.Element("ForecastTime")} Temperature: {xForecast.Element("Temperature")}";
    }
}
```

To retrieve the `Location` element that has the value of `4` in its `LocationId` element, you can call it like this:

```
var location =
    xml
    .Descendants("Location")
    .First(match => match.IsMatchLocationId(4));
```

From `location` you can get the `LocationData` element:

```
var locationData = location.Element("LocationData");
```

From `locationData` you can get a list of `Forecast` elements. It is here that the custom `Format` extension can be called. You will probably want to do a lot more in `Format` than the basic example I've shown.

```
var forecasts = locationData.Elements("Forecast").Select(forecast => forecast.Format());
```

That's really all there is to it.

---

**TESTBENCH**
[image: console output]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        XElement xml;
#if true
        xml = XElement.Parse(minimalSource);
#else
        // WARNING: This download took around 30 seconds when I tried it.
        WebClient ftp = new WebClient();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
            ftp.OpenRead(@"https://ims.gov.il/sites/default/files/ims_data/xml_files/isr_cities_1week_6hr_forecast.xml")))
        {
            xml = XElement.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
#endif
        // NEEDS ERROR CHECKING FOR NULLS AND SUCH!
        // Obtain the location.
        var location =
            xml
            .Descendants("Location")
            .First(match => match.IsMatchLocationId(4));

        Console.WriteLine(
            $"City: {location.Element("LocationMetaData").Element("LocationNameEng")}");
        var locationData = location.Element("LocationData");
        var forecasts = locationData.Elements("Forecast").Select(forecast => forecast.Format());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", forecasts));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
    }
}

const string minimalSource =
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<LocationForecasts>
    <Identification>
        <Organization>Israel Meteorological Service</Organization>
        <Title>6-hours forecast for 80 cities</Title>
        <IssueDateTime>Sun Jul 17 18:45:24 IDT 2022</IssueDateTime>
    </Identification>
    <Location>
        <LocationMetaData>
            <LocationId>1</LocationId>
            <LocationNameEng>Jerusalem</LocationNameEng>
            <DisplayLat>31.7780</DisplayLat>
            <DisplayLon>35.2000</DisplayLon>
            <DisplayHeight>780</DisplayHeight>
        </LocationMetaData>
        <LocationData>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 03:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>19</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>90</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>6</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>113</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>17</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>18</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>0</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>19</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>19</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>19</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>20</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>0</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>0</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
         </LocationData>
    </Location>    <Location>
        <LocationMetaData>
            <LocationId>4</LocationId>
            <LocationNameEng>Rishon le Zion</LocationNameEng>
            <DisplayLat>31.9640</DisplayLat>
            <DisplayLon>34.8040</DisplayLon>
            <DisplayHeight>50</DisplayHeight>
        </LocationMetaData>
        <LocationData>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 03:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>24</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>76</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>3</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>360</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>19</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>22</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>0</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>24</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>24</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>21</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>26</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>0</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>0</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 09:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>28</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>64</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>9</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>68</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>20</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>25</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>2</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>29</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>28</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>22</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>28</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>4</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>4</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 15:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>29</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>56</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>18</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>113</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>20</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>26</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>2</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>31</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>29</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1220</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>28</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>30</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>6</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>10</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
            <Forecast>
                <ForecastTime>2022-07-16 21:00:00</ForecastTime>
                <Temperature>26</Temperature>
                <RelativeHumidity>68</RelativeHumidity>
                <WindSpeed>8</WindSpeed>
                <WindDirection>180</WindDirection>
                <DewPointTemp>20</DewPointTemp>
                <HeatStress>24</HeatStress>
                <HeatStressLevel>1</HeatStressLevel>
                <FeelsLike>26</FeelsLike>
                <WindChill>26</WindChill>
                <Rain>0.00</Rain>
                <WeatherCode>1250</WeatherCode>
                <MinTemp>26</MinTemp>
                <MaxTemp>30</MaxTemp>
                <UVIndex>0</UVIndex>
                <UVIndexMax>4</UVIndexMax>
            </Forecast>
        </LocationData>
    </Location> 
</LocationForecasts>";
```